# Configuring HP Laserjet Pro MFP M128fn with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, printing, hp, hplip, laserjet

I have a network printer HP Laserjet Pro MFP M128fn, while Ubuntu 14.04 is able to detect the printer using Hplip 3.15.9 but no printing can be done and it keeps showing the status "waiting for the printer to finish".

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to use my network HP printer until I installed HP Linux Imaging and Printing (http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html). Take a look here too https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HPPrinterInstallation.